# Initialize Flask-SocketIO python app on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-socketio

I'm new to python, so this might be a dumb question, but I have the following issue:

I'm trying to deploy a Flask-SocketIO app to heroku, my app.py looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
opt: Dict[Any, Any] = {}
.
.
@socketio.on('connect')
def joined():
   test = json.dumps(opt)
   emit('test', test)
.
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
   opt = setup_args()
   socketio.run(app)
```

My procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker app:app
```

If i run `heroku local` my server starts as expected, and I can establish a socket conection with my client, but my variable `opt` seems not to be filled. From what i've read in the docs, this is because the procfile does the `socketio.run(app)` for me, and my `__main__` part is not getting executed.
I need to somehow trigger a method that initializes some variables in my app.py.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply move ```opt = setup_args()``` out of the if statment, and move it, say, somewhere at the top of the file? Because this would solve the problem. If you want ```opt``` to be used for each request, you should use object ```g```.

Comment: well, that was it.. thank you! So what is object g for? is it to set the variable ``global`` before assignment? If I understand it correctly, if I assign a variable in a function scope, it's only available in that function, if I use ``global opt`` ``opt = setup_args()`` the global variable ``opt`` is assigned. is that correct?

Comment: Object ```g``` is available to you on every request. And your other statements seem to be correct.

Comment: PS: I posted my comment as an answer too. So if you mark it as the correct answer and give an up vote others can easier spot what the correct answer is. :)

Comment: Ok, I have one mor issue now: if I try to change something in my opt dict like this: ``opt['agent'] = xyz`` I get the following error: ``NameError: name 'opt' is not defined`` So that means that my variable is not initialized if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes, it does. As you stated before, this means that the variable ```opt``` is not defined in your scope. However, if you have another question, please open a new one and post example code accordingly. Otherwise others get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't simply move `opt = setup_args()` out of the if statment, and move it, say, somewhere at the top of the file?